# Не выдает "alert" при отправке формы?

Tags: jquery

В общем не могу понять почему alert не выдает когда форма не заполненна?

```js
$(function() {

  var selectTerritory = $('#selectTerritory').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registration.php",
    data: {
      Territory: selectTerritory
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#detale').html(data);
      $('#selectTerritory').val(selectTerritory);
    }
  });

  $('#selectTerritory').change(function() {
    var selectTerritory = $(this).val(),
      name = $('#inputName').val(),
      email = $('#inputMail').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registration.php",
      // beforesend:(presend()),
      data: {
        Territory: selectTerritory,
        name: name,
        email: email
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#detale').html(data);
        $('#selectTerritory').val(selectTerritory);
        $('#inputName').val(name);
        $('#inputMail').val(email);
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('change', '#selectRayons', function() {
    var selectRayons = $('#selectRayons').val(),
      selectTerritory = $('#selectTerritory').val(),
      name = $('#inputName').val(),
      email = $('#inputMail').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registration.php",
      // beforesend:(presend()),
      data: {
        Rayons: selectRayons,
        Territory: selectTerritory,
        name: name,
        email: email
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#detale').html(data);
        $('#selectRayons').val(selectRayons);
        $('#inputName').val(name);
        $('#inputMail').val(email);
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('change', '#selectTowns', function() {
    var selectTerritory = $('#selectTerritory').val(),
      selectRayons = $('#selectRayons').val(),
      selectTowns = $('#selectTowns').val(),
      name = $('#inputName').val(),
      email = $('#inputMail').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registration.php",
      // beforesend:(presend()),
      data: {
        Rayons: selectRayons,
        Territory: selectTerritory,
        Towns: selectTowns,
        name: name,
        email: email
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#detale').html(data);
        $('#selectTerritory').val(selectTerritory);
        $('#selectRayons').val(selectRayons);
        $('#selectTowns').val(selectTowns);
        $('#inputName').val(name);
        $('#inputMail').val(email);
      }
    });
  });

  $("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var form = $($this);
    var error = false;
    form.find('*').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        alert('Зaпoлнитe пoлe "' + $(this).attr('placeholder') + '"!');
        error = true;
      }
    })
  });

  if (!error) {
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registration.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function(data) {
        form.find('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data['error']) {
          alert(data['error']);
        } else {
          alert('Форма отравлена!');
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        form.find('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

});
```

Comment: что это такое `$($this)`?

Comment: Потому что отрабатывает действие по-умолчанию - submit. До вашего submit не доходит. Либо вы убираете input[type="submit"] либо button, что там у вас, и отправляете форму по клику на кнопку. Тогда контролировать можно. Либо прерывать стандартное поведение и отправлять форму ajax запросом. Собственно давно пора отправлять формы без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: @SlyDeath, вы что-то совсем не по теме. алерт тут должен сработать и без прерывания (и вообще оно тут может есть, код явно не весь, тк error для чего-то используется дальше). И аякс тут вообще причем? Ловить сабмит только по кнопке это ну очень плохой тон.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev страничка всё равно перезагрузится. В его случае не работает из-за `$($this)`

Comment: @SlyDeath Вот я дополнил код, он работает но не польностью. Алерт не выдает.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман у вас очепятка. Исправьте `var form = $($this);` на `var form = $(this);` у $this доллар лишний.

Comment: @ SlyDeath уже исправил)) Спасибо))

Comment: @SlyDeath  а как можно было бы оптимизировать такое колличество аякс запросов?